# Android Rotation Programming which Sensor?

Tags: android, sensors, android-sensors

I'm working on my first Android project, and I have seen many code snippets on various types of rotation and I need a bit of clarification.
Imagine holding the phone/tablet in landscape mode and it's turned like a steering wheel. I want the 2D background to turn in real time with the phone/tablet. Which sensor would I use?

Comment: FYI, you are getting down-voted for a lack of effort on your part. As the tooltip says "This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful"

Comment: I know the two main types used for rotation are gyroscope and orientation, but which would be the better option for the scenario i posted

Comment: You should include what you know and anything you have learned from research in your question. At best we can't know how much you do and at worst people assume you are just asking for a hand out.

Comment: My question is plain, which sensor should I use for a real time rotation of a 2D image, I'm not asking for code snippets or a how-to. Just which sensor.

Comment: So which part of the documentation was confusing or unclear to you when you read through them? I can help clear any ambiguities up for you.

Comment: Rotation Vector: Measures the orientation of a device by providing the three elements of the device's rotation vector.

Gyroscope:Measures a device's rate of rotation in rad/s around each of the three physical axes (x, y, and z).

documentation a little vague as to how theyre different

Comment: The former three elements are the device's rotation around its X, Y and Z axes. Together they describe the 3d orientation of the device. The gyroscope tells you "how fast" it is changing rotation.

Comment: yes I got that, but which would be best for a 2d rotation? the vector or the gyroscope?

Answer (score 0):

```
(SensorManager) getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE)
```

You can use SensorManager of android